# Regexp and powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a, probably, simple task that im trying to solve - so far without any success.
I want to use powershell to parse and match a string into variables.
The string is of the form

```
"Message
-------
RECORDING XYZ started recording on 2016-11-08 19:58:03 and stopped on 2016-11-08 20:33:00 as scheduled."
```

and i want it to produce three variables $title = "RECORDING XYZ", $start_time = "2016-11-08 19:58:03", $stop_time = "2016-11-08 20:33:00".

Is regexp the way to go or does powershell has any simpler functions? ive been looking at -split and -match for ex.

Please does any one have to time to give me a hand?
Regards

---

Edit:

Mathias answer lead me to this solution

```
    $text = "Message
-------
RECORDING XYZ started recording on 2016-11-08 19:58:03 and stopped on 2016-11-08 20:33:00 as scheduled."

$lines = $text -split "\n"

$lines[2] -match "^(.+) started recording on (.+) and stopped on (.+) as scheduled."

Write-Output $Matches[1]
```

Simple but it works

Comment: Something along the line of $text = "Message
-------
RECORDING XYZ started recording on 2016-11-08 19:58:03 and stopped on 2016-11-08 20:33:00 as scheduled."$a = $text -split "\n"
$b = $a -match "^(.+)\sstarted recording on\s(.+) and stopped on (.+) as scheduled."
$title = $t[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [named capture group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#named_matched_subexpression) to grab several matches from the string:

```
if($text -match "-`r?`n(?<recording>.*) started recording on (?<starttime>[\d\-\:\s]+) and stopped on (?<stoptime>[\d\-\:\s]+) as scheduled.") {
    $title = $Matches['recording']
    $start_time = $Matches['starttime']
    $stop_time = $Matches['stoptime']
}
```

Comment: Cheers m8 - that didnt quite work for me but it lead me to a working solution (see my edit of the question)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your attempt  (that you mentioned in the comment) with split

```
$text = "Message ------- RECORDING XYZ started recording on 2016-11-08 19:58:03 and stopped on 2016-11-08 20:33:00 as scheduled."
$a = $text -split "\n" 
$arr = ((($a -split "Message ------- " )-split "started recording on") -split "and stopped on") -split "as scheduled."

$title = $arr[1]
$start_time = $arr[2]
$stop_time = $arr[3]

write-host $title $start_time $stop_time
```